# send parameters while uploading file

Tags: android, servlets, upload, httpconnection

I've got this piece of code http://pastebin.com/VrMNuxcv which successfully uploads a file onto the server from my android.

I have to send a couple of string parameters together with it.

For that i have given

```
 conn.setRequestProperty("x-myapp-param1", "Parameter 1 text");
```

On the  server side (Servlet DoPsot method)

I tried to retrieve the string parameter by

```
String userId = request.getParameter("myapp-param1");
```

But the

```
 userId is null
```

My code in the client part is given below:

```
    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP
                                     // connection to
                                     // the URL
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("file_name", fileName);
            conn.setRequestProperty("x-myapp-param1", "Parameter 1 text"); 
           dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_name\";filename=\""
                + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available

();
```

Server code:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    

        String userId = request.getParameter("myapp-param1");
        String x_user_id = request.getParameter("x-myapp-param1");
        System.out.println("userId getParameter  : "+userId +"x_user_id  :  "+ x_user_id);
        System.out.println("request.getHeaderNames();"+request.getHeaderNames());
        System.out.println("request.getHeaderNames();"+request.getHeaders("x"));


        File filenameImg = null;
        List<FileItem> items = null;
        try {
            items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory())
                    .parseRequest(request);
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
        }

        for (FileItem item : items) {



            if (item.isFormField()) {



                // Process regular form fields here the same way as
                // request.getParameter().
                // You can get parameter name by

                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();       
                String fieldvalue = item.getString(); 
                System.out.println("user_id===fieldname======: "+fieldname);
                //System.out.println("user_id====fieldvalue=====: "+fieldvalue);
                // You can get parameter value by item.getString();
            } else {

                try{
                    // Process uploaded fields here.
                    String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                    // Get filename.
                    String path = GetWebApplicationPathServlet.getContext().getRealPath("/images");

                    File file =  new File(path,filename);


                    // Define destination file.

                    item.write(file);
                    System.out.println("filename: "+filename);
                    System.out.println("file: "+file);
                    request.setAttribute("image", file);
                    filenameImg = file;
                    // Write to destination file.
                //  request.setAttribute("image", filename);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two major problems:

1. The [`URLConnection#setRequestProperty()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) sets the HTTP request **header**, not the HTTP request **parameter**. Those are two entirely different things. In case of `multipart/form-data` requests, you need to write them as a fullworthy multipart part. You can find a detailed example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) (check the section *Uploading Files* near the bottom).
2. In case of a HTTP `multipart/form-data` request, the parameters are not available by [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29). You need to treat them as **multipart parts** and not as request parameters. You can parse them using [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload), or when you're already on Servlet 3.0, using [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29). You're already using Apache Commons FileUpload, so just keep that part and get rid of the unnecessary `getParameter()` calls. The regular parameters are available in the secion commented as "Process regular form fields here".

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling

You do

```
conn.setRequestProperty("x-myapp-param1", "Parameter 1 text");
```

and

```
String userId = request.getParameter("myapp-param1");
```

Notice the missing x- on the receiver side.

Comment: I added String x_user_id = request.getParameter("x-myapp-param1");  aslo in my code.. But still the value is null

Answer (score 1):

I realized my Fileupload by adding the appace-mime libarys, they support entities.

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT); 

            for(int index=0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) { 
                ContentBody cb;
                if(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("File")) { 
                    File file = new File(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue());
                    FileBody isb = new FileBody(file,"application/*");

                    /*
                    byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    fis.read(data);
                    fis.close();

                    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,"application/*","File");
                    entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), bab);
                    */  
                    entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), isb);
                } else { 
                    // Normal string data 
                    cb =  new StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue(),"", null);
                    entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(),cb); 
                } 
            } 


            httpost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206039/android-fileupload-with-https-and-credentials/5459685#5459685

Comment: My requirement is to access the parameter value in servlet