# Android Http Credentials Login

Tags: android, json, http, authentication, credentials

**Pictures of the link in the user name and password to login. Because the Json need to read the data. It is with Android, how do I do that ?**

```
@Override protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
return GET(urls[0]);
}
@Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
if(result == null) {
progress.show();
Log.i("Arduino Server ", "[ Server Bağlantısı Kuruluyor ]");
} else {
progress.dismiss();
Log.i("Arduino Server ", "[ Server Bağlantısı Kuruldu ]");
}

try {
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
outlet10 = json.getString("outlet10").toString();
outlet11 = json.getString("outlet11").toString();
outlet12 = json.getString("outlet12").toString();
outlet13 = json.getString("outlet13").toString();
outlet14 = json.getString("outlet14").toString();
outlet15 = json.getString("outlet15").toString();

if (outlet10.equals("on")) { Switch1.setChecked(true);  }else{ Switch1.setChecked(false); }
if (outlet11.equals("on")) { Switch2.setChecked(true);  }else{ Switch2.setChecked(false); }
if (outlet12.equals("on")) { Switch3.setChecked(true);  }else{ Switch3.setChecked(false); }
if (outlet13.equals("on")) { Switch4.setChecked(true);  }else{ Switch4.setChecked(false); }
if (outlet14.equals("on")) { Switch5.setChecked(true);  }else{ Switch5.setChecked(false); }
if (outlet15.equals("on")) { Switch6.setChecked(true);  }else{ Switch6.setChecked(false); }

} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("Json Durumlar ", "Alındı...");
}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bu linkteki örneğe bakabilir misin? yardımcı olabilir

[birinci link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android)
[ikinci link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459685/1332870)

Comment: Ersin bey, denedim ama login kısmını bir türlü geçemedim. şifreyi kaldırdığımda Outlet değerleri okuyabiliyorum ama sayfa güvenliksiz oluyor.

Comment: güncelledim cevabımı , iki tane yeni link koydum

Comment: Ersin bey, deniyorum ama İlgili Activity aktif olunca program hata veriyor ve durduruldu diyor. Şifre alanını geçip durumları okuyamıyorum. ve Ayrıca Content = application/json

Comment: who can help I guess :((